# Best way verify existence of a row in a table via Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Currently I'm using `by.repeater` for getting all rows of a table and then check each row to see if it's matching my desired information. It seems to be too redundant. How can I do better?

```
      element.all(by.repeater("userRole in roles")).each(function(row){
        row.getText().then(function(text){
          if(text.indexOf(ROLE_NAME) > -1){
            expect(row.$('.role').getText()).toContain(ROLE_NAME);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: There are several ways to do that, what does your table look like? Could you give us more details about what you want to test? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each` will resolve promises, so we can gather all the text in rows and then use `toContain` on the array.

```
var textRows = element.all(by.repeater("userRole in roles")).each(function(row){
        return row.getText();
});

expect(textRows).toContain(ROLE_NAME);
```

One other option is to use `Array.prototype.some` to use a function for validating a row:

```
var textRows = element.all(by.repeater("userRole in roles")).each(function(row){
        return row.getText();
});
var hasAValidRow = textRows.some(function(row){ return row.indexOf(ROLE_NAME) > -1; });
expect(hasAValidRow).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Hi, In my case i'm getting Message:'Expected undefined to match abc.'. Promise is not resolved and generates a race condition?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on a similar problem, after many hours I got it working using:

```
var rows = $$('#ss-personal-phone-action-panel');
rows.each(function(row) {
    var rowElems = row.$$('td.destination');
    expect(rowElems.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(rowElems.get(0).getText()).toMatch(testTelephone);
});
```

I hope this help